# How to get the True Negative Rate from this code?

Tags: classification, python, binary-data

I want to calculate the TNR.  I am in a larger code project and we have this one binary classifier.

The major problem is that I don't find the information about the variables in the code.
What is the `benign rate`,  `guesses`  and `ad rate`,  `guesses`? And to calculate the TNR of that?
I am guessing that the TNR is `TNR = 2*benign_rate/len(y_hat)`.

```py
y_hat  = np.array([0, 1])
y_test = np.array([0, 1])

benign_rate = 0
benign_guesses = 0
ad_guesses = 0
ad_rate = 0
for i in range(len(y_hat)):
    if y_hat[i] == 0:
        benign_guesses += 1
        if y_test[i] == 0:
            benign_rate += 1
    else:
        ad_guesses += 1
        if y_test[i] == 1:
            ad_rate += 1

    if y_test[i] == 1:
        if y_hat[i] == 0:

acc = (benign_rate+ad_rate)/len(y_hat)        
TP = 2*ad_rate/len(y_hat)

precision = ad_rate/ad_guesses
recall = round(100*TPR, 2)
TPR = 2 * ad_rate / len(y_hat)

TNR = 2*benign_rate/len(y_hat)
```

Comment: You have the predicted (`y_hat`) and true (`y_test`) values, right? Then, TNR is `np.sum((y_hat == 0) & (y_test == 0)) / np.sum(y_test == 0)`.

Comment: @alex I get this using your suggestion: 

RES:, AUC, ACC, PRE, TPR, F1, TNR, FNR
RES:,100.0,90.7,100.0,81.4,89.75,100.0,18.6

How to countercheck this? and that it would be the solution I think :)

It is btw the same as my current TNR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The True Negative Ratio is the fraction of the correctly classified negative samples from all negative samples.

You can compute it using numpy:

```py
correct_negative = np.sum((y_hat == 0) & (y_test == 0))
total_negative = np.sum(y_test == 0)

TNR = correct_negative / total_negative
```

or you can do it "manually":

```py
correct_negative = 0
total_negative = 0

for i in range(len(y_hat)):
    if y_test[i] == 0:
        total_negative += 1
        if y_hat[i] == 0:
            correct_negative += 1

TNR = correct_negative / total_negative
```